# core utilisation in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've written a program that reads through a WAV file and gathers various data then does certain calculations and outputs whatever useful information I need (the end point is a voice discriminator). This all happens individually for each file in a separate class object, only needing a different input string for each, so I figured I could quite easily thread up the application and I could have it running four times faster or so.

This I've done, and it seems to work nicely. However, when I came to time the application (threaded vs non-threaded) I only gained about 3 seconds over a minute to work through ~3600 files. My best guess for this is file I/O and I'll see greater improvements with all tests implemented, but that's not what I'm interested in particularly.

With Task Manager open on Win7 both versions of the application were showing similar activity on all four (virtual) cores on my i3 machine which then all dropped to minimum on completion.

So my question: Does c# compiler, and Visual Studio in particular, already optimise for multiple cores? and if not, have I missed something fundamental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without more detail but if you otherwise implemented the various thread functions correctly and use an appropriate number of threads for the hardware you're running your code on, your CPU utilization should be good in a threaded implementation.

If you don't use multiple threads for processing, your program will use a single CPU / single core - the compiler doesn't rearrange your code for multiple threads if that's what you're asking.

If you see the same kind of CPU utilization for both single-threaded and multithreaded code, there could be a number of reasons for that (just guessing since I don't know your code):

- You use too few / too many threads
- Disk I/O is soo much that all gains from threads are washed out
- You have so many other processes / threads running on your system that they interfere with your measurement

There may be a number of other reasons but as Allan Elder's answer mentions, you can give the Parallels library a try - it'll try to pick an optimal number of threads for your code based on various factors. It makes using threads a lot simpler since the boilerplate code to hook up threads is done for you.

When I did similar processing on image files, using multiple threads cut my processing time down by 40% (although I loaded most images into memory - they weren't streaming so I/O wasn't as much of a factor). Core utilization was also much better with the multithreaded approach in my case - it was 8 cores vs. 1 core.

Comment: I just turned on all my tests and turned off the log files and timed again: 20 seconds vs 35. So yeah, my performance was drowning in disk I/O as expected. I'd already established most of this, but thanks for putting it so clearly. I mostly wanted to check I wasn't missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the TPL; the Task Parallel Library.

Specifically, you can use Parallel.ForEach statement to process your files.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx